# Cómo ordenar una consulta según la relacion, laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

tengo esta consulta

```
  $site =  Site::where('place_id', $siteGroup->place_id)->whereHas('template', function ($query){
               $query->where('type', TemplateType::PLACE);
            })->whereHas('locationGroupPlace')->get();
```

en la cual quiero ordenar todos los `site` según la columna "type" de mi relación `locationGroupPlace`

haciendo una subconsulta como esta, obtengo el mismo resultado desordenado

```
    $site = Site::where('place_id', $siteGroup->place_id)->whereHas('template', function ($query){
       $query->where('type', TemplateType::PLACE);
    })->whereHas('locationGroupPlace', function ($query){
        $query->orderBy('type', 'asc');
    })->get();
```

cabe destacar que quiero ordenar todos los sites según una columna de su relación, no ordenar la relación :)